# Select all rows, with specific characteristics, with same subdata by grouping them through a same row value in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery

I have a table with the next structure:

```
Data structure: 
| CONTRACT | CONNECTION | STATE |
|    1     |    AAA     |   Y   |
|    2     |    AAA     |   Y   |
|    3     |    BBB     |   N   |
|    4     |    BBB     |   N   |
|    5     |    BBB     |   N   |
|    6     |    BBB     |   N   |
|    7     |    AAA     |   Y   |
|    8     |    CCC     |   Y   |
|    9     |    CCC     |   N   |
|    10    |    AAA     |   Y   |
|    11    |    CCC     |   N   |
```

I'd like to select all rows/data that, considering groups defined by CONNECTION column as groups AAA, BBB and CCC, the query have to select only groups that have **all** rows of the STATE column with the value 'N', but always considering all data of the group.
So the result on the table would be:

```
Result needed: 
| CONTRACT | CONNECTION | STATE |
|    3     |    BBB     |   N   |
|    4     |    BBB     |   N   |
|    5     |    BBB     |   N   |
|    6     |    BBB     |   N   |
```

I've looking for functions like decode, exists and so on but just don't see how solve this problem.

Any idea of how could I write a query for this purpose?

Comment: Thank you very much to all. I've tried _Felix Pamittan_ answer and it worked fine.

Comment: All 3 solutions should work but [Giorgos Betsos' Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36834763/1509264) will only scan the table/index once whereas using `IN` or `NOT EXISTS` and a correlated sub-query will scan the table/index in the sub-query and in the outer-query and is likely to be doing much more IO. If you view the explain plans for the two queries you can count the number of table (or index) scans yourself and can look at the differing amounts of IO for each solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SUM` and `HAVING`:

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/477671)</kbd>

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl t
WHERE
    CONNECTION IN(
        SELECT CONNECTION
        FROM tbl
        GROUP BY CONNECTION
        HAVING
            SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
            AND SUM(CASE WHEN STATE <> 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
    )
```

The first condition in the `HAVING` clause makes sure that the `CONNECTION` has at least one `STATE = 'N'`. The second one makes sure that the `CONNECTION` has no other `STATE`s than `'N'`.

Comment: `SUM(CASE WHEN STATE = 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0` is superfluous as there must exist at least one row to be grouping by and you have excluded all all other states with the `SUM(CASE WHEN STATE <> 'N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0` filter.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT CONTRACT, CONNECTION, STATE
FROM (
  SELECT CONTRACT, CONNECTION, STATE,
         COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE <> 'N' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY CONNECTION) AS cnt
  FROM mytable) t
WHERE t.cnt  = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use windowed `COUNT`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *
   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE = 'N' THEN 1 END) OVER(PARTITION BY CONNECTION) AS num_of_n
   ,COUNT(CASE WHEN STATE <> 'N' OR STATE IS NULL THEN 1 END) 
          OVER(PARTITION BY CONNECTION) AS num_of_non_n
  FROM mytable
)
SELECT CONTRACT, CONNECTION, STATE
FROM cte
WHERE num_of_n > 0 AND num_of_non_n = 0;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/GFT83874)**</kbd>

---

Or correlated subquery:

```
SELECT *
FROM mytable m1
WHERE STATE = 'N'
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM mytable m2
                  WHERE m1.CONNECTION = m2.CONNECTION
                    AND (STATE <> 'N' OR STATE IS NULL));
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo 2`](http://rextester.com/SYNY24144)**</kbd>